# Entity Framework ObjectStateEntries in Order of Dependency/Save Order

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I need to get all the ObjectStateEntries from my ObjectStateManager in the order that they will be saved (in order of dependency that is). Is there any easy way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way to plug into the saving process if Entity Framework in order to perform some custom logic.

Here is an example how to extend a simple NorthwindEntities model and do some work during the adding/updating/deleting process:

```
public partial class NorthwindEntities
{
    partial void OnContextCreated()
    {
        SavingChanges += OnSavingChanges;
    }

    private void OnSavingChanges(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var context = sender as NorthwindEntities;

        if (context != null)
        {
            context.DetectChanges();

            var objectStateManager = context.ObjectStateManager;

            foreach (var entry in objectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added | EntityState.Modified | EntityState.Deleted))
            {
                switch (entry.State)
                {
                    case EntityState.Added:
                        // Perform custom 'add' logic here
                        break;
                    case EntityState.Modified:
                        // Perform custom 'update' logic here
                        break;
                    case EntityState.Deleted:
                        // Perform custom 'delete' logic here
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't get me the ObjectStateEntries in order of dependency as they will actually be persisted to the DB...

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include a specific example of what you are trying to achieve? I'd like to try and help but it's not clear to me what is your scenario